# Using logistic regression to estimate whether probability of an outcome is greater than chance (and by how much)?

Tags: logistic, generalized-linear-model, regression-coefficients, logit, odds-ratio

I have an outcome variable that is subjects' correct or incorrect responses to a single question asked at two time points (before and after the experiment). I want to know if subjects were better than chance at answering these questions and by how much (i.e., obtain an effect size). I already know from a separate analysis that performance didn't vary depending on when the question was asked, so I think the most appropriate approach is to treat the responses as successes/failures and use the following code to run a model comparison, one estimating the intercept and one leaving it out and comparing the models using the likelihood ratio test to determine if the intercept-only model is more likely:

```
df$successes<-df$question1+df$question2
df$failures<-2-df$successes
modela<-glm(formula = cbind(df$successes, df$failures) ~ 1, family = binomial)
modelc<-glm(formula = cbind(d$successes, d$failures) ~ 0, family = binomial)
anova(modela, modelc)
```

I will interpret the exponent of intercept estimate (exp(2.6692) = 14.42) as the odds ratio relative to chance (e.g., Subjects' probability of responding correctly was 14 times higher than would be expected by chance.

Is this correct?

EDIT: I didn't realize this approach wasn't addressing the repeated measurement issue. To do so I propose the following code instead:

```
modela<-glmer(df$outcome ~ 1 + (1|df$ID), family=binomial)
modelc<-glmer(df$outcome ~ 0 + (1|df$ID), family=binomial)
```

Note, the data are melted in this case so that the responses (0 vs. 1) to the two questions are in the same column and ID is the variable that identifies multiple responses from the same individual.

Is this okay? The results seem interpretable. Or is there a simpler way to do this that gives me an effect size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this isn't correct because the model treats all the trials as independent, when in reality they were grouped into pairs by subject. (And besides, in the case of independent trials, a [binomial test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_test) is a much simpler approach to this problem.)

One way to account for this grouping is to augment your logistic-regression models with a batch of random effects, with one random effect per subject.

Comment: Thanks. For some reason I thought this approach addressed the issue of linked observations but I guess I was wrong. I did as you suggested and ran a GLMM instead. Can you let me know if this is correct and if this is the most straightforward way to do this and to obtain an effect size (odds ratio)? I don't want to run an overly sophisticated model if it's not necessary, but I'm more familiar with regression these days so I don't always think of more basic approaches.

Comment: "For some reason I thought this approach addressed the issue of linked observations" — Yeah, it's an easy mistake to make because of R's interface which lets you specify trial counts. In reality, under the hood, logistic regression always has dichotomous outcomes, whose probabilities differ only with the covariates. "Can you let me know if this is correct and if this is the most straightforward way to do this and to obtain an effect size (odds ratio)?" — Yeah, I think it's correct, and I can't think of a simpler way that properly accounts for the grouping by subject.